# install pymysql to specific directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pymysql

I am trying to install pymysql to `/home/king/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/` but it keeps going somewhere else. Note that when I ran every other package install (eg `pip3 install pandas`) everything worked fine and I could immediately use the package in a Jupyter notebook. What am I doing wrong? I tried:

1. `sudo pip3 install PyMySQL`

returns 'directory not owned by current user'

2. `pip3 install PyMySQL`

appears to work fine, but when I run a `import pymysql` inside of a Jupyter notebook it cant load the module

3. downloading the .zip from github and installing with: `sudo python3 setup.py install`

installed to: `Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyMySQL-0.8.0-py3.5.egg`

4. trying to install the .zip without sudo: `python3 setup.py install`

Permission denied: `/home/king/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/test-easy-install-16270.write-test`

5. `conda install pandas` worked fine (said pkg already installed). `conda install pymysql`

failed with permission denied. When I tried `sudo conda install pymysql` it couldnt find conda. When I attempted to install conda as sudo it said `ERROR: File or directory already exists: '/home/king/anaconda3'`

Comment: try `conda install pandas`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I updated my post with the results (#5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up dicovering tthat pymysql was install correctly in an older version of python (3.5) so I copied the directory to my 3.6 folder and everything worked perfectly

```
sudo cp -r pymysql /home/king/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
```